# Пример использования OpenSSL API (видимо DH.H) для реализации обмена ключами по DH

Tags: openssl

Ищу на C пример использования OpenSSL API  (видимо DH.H) для реализации обмена ключами по DH.
 Поделиться кто компактным Си-шником, демонстрирующий процесс предельно аскетичным способом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Тестовый проект тут:*
https://github.com/SysMan-One/DH

*Содержит исключительно демонстрацию метода.*